# What is the Placeholder sign in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

What is the PlaceHolder sign in `Hive` (`HiveQL`)?. Like other languages has "?" or "$" sign.

Comment: Can you add which languages have `?` and `$` ?

Answer (score 0):

hiveconf for variable substitution.
So, in the hive command line interface you can set a variable using set and can use it by ${hiveconf:variable}
example :

```html
hive> set DATE_NOW='2016-10-1';
hive> select * from cal where day >= '${hiveconf:DATE_NOW}'
```